# Using jQuery UI sortable across browser windows

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, popup

I'm trying to use jQuery UI's sortable to make list items in a browser popup window (i.e., `window.open()`, not some kind of modal) sortable.
Basically:

```
popup = window.open("", "_blank").document.body;
list = popup.appendChild(...);
$(list).sortable();
```

However, it seems like the positioning calculations within jQuery UI are getting messed up.
Dragging things around doesn't show fluid movement---nothing seems to happen, but clicking around enough will move elements all over the page (they're stuck with position: absolute styles).

Running jQuery UI sortable on the same styling/markup within the popup window itself works fine, so it seems like the issue stems from jQuery on the parent window trying to calculation positions in the child window's DOM.
Passing a container on the child DOM to jQuery UI sortable's `containment` option doesn't help.

Is there some way I can tell the parent window jQuery that it needs to be doing all of its calculations with respect to the child window's document?

Comment: Could you please post a jsfiddle with your partially working code? It would help quite a bit.

Comment: The application code is all ClojureScript, actually, so no jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably elect to bypass the problem, and simply create a blank document that includes a container and JS wrappers for any functions that you wish to call from the parent -- instead of opening a completely blank document, open a principally empty document that contains any necessary functions in built as well as its own references to the jQuery libraries, but which accepts function calls from the parent to populate it (eg, popup.FunctionName(var) and so forth).  If the child needs to communicate with the parent, you can perform it in the same way basically.

That way, you simply void any of the problems that you get with jQuery getting fuzzy over the scope of its actions by isolating the jQuery calls, essentially only ever calling them within the window that they are supposed to be affecting.

Comment: Bypassing the problem in the method you describe works well; thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with DoctorJest that opening another window probably isn't the best solution here. If you're already using the jquery UI have you considered a `.dialog()`? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sinetheta/QfbsD/5/)

```
$( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
    modal: true,
    open: function(){
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    }
});
```

Comment: The popup needs to be printable as a separate document, so dialog is out. Otherwise, yeah, it'd be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

One solution (below) would be to use the HTML5 drag-and-drop API to create sortable lists that are connected (i.e. you can drag from the popup to the parent and vice-versa).

The other would be to simply copy the relevant jQuery UI functionality, in this case jquery.ui.sortable.js, to the popup window. But, you would not be able to drag from the popup window to the parent window.

### Solution 1:

This uses the jQuery HTML5 Sortable plugin by Ali Farhadi to create a multi-window sortable list.

JavaScript:

```
var popup = window.open("", "_blank").document.body;
var list = popup.appendChild($("#list")[0]);
var parentList = $("#parent-list")[0];

$(parentList).sortable({
    connectWith: ".connected"
});

$(list).sortable({
    connectWith: ".connected"
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/VED6D/

*I am working on the second solution but I do not know how feasible it is yet.*